# How to solve insertOne is not a function problem

Tags: node.js, mongodb

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';

MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, db){

  if(err) throw err;

  var dbo = db.db('mydb');

  var myObj = [{name: 'Company Inc', address: 'Highway 37'}];
  dbo.createCollection('Customers').insertone(myObj, function(err, res){

    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('1 document inserted!');
    db.close();
  });
});
```

My code is not working, the error is insertOne is not a function. My mongoDB shell version is 3.4.18 and npm installed mongodb module is 3.1.10.

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting your record without creating the collection, as insertOne will automatically create the collection if it does not exist.

```
var MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;
var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/';
MongoClient.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true}, function(err, db){
  if(err) throw err;
  var dbo = db.db('mydb');
  var myObj = [{name: 'Company Inc', address: 'Highway 37'}];
  var collection = db.collection('Customers');
  collection.insertOne(myObj, function(err, res){
    if(err) throw err;
    console.log('1 document inserted!');
    db.close();
  });
});
```

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insertOne/

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: i mean i can't get your answer, please can show corrections on my code straightway

Comment: If this isn't working, then the issue must be sometime else. I don't know what it could be.

Answer (score 1):

just check the case of letter o in your insertOne function ..

Comment: Generally if a question can be resolved by fixing a typo, flag it as "Not-reproducible or caused by typo."